# Why empty .git/lfs/tmp/ objects are created?

Tags: git, git-lfs

We did a simple `cp -R repo1 test/` thinking that we would get the same number of files in dir test/repo1 as dir repo1

But we notice that new objects are created in the following paths after running `git status` -

./.git/lfs/tmp/3456789021

./.git/lfs/tmp/3452229021

./.git/lfs/tmp/3456449021

./.git/lfs/tmp/3456449000

1. Why are new files created in there with a `git status` command ?
2. How do we get exact copy of files in dir repo1 in another directory ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Git stores data in the index that includes information about the creation time, the device number, and the inode number of each file, and that information generally changes when files are copied and cannot be copied from one file to another.  Git uses this information to determine when a file has changed.

In this case, since the file has changed (since the data in the index doesn't match), when you run `git status`, Git invokes Git LFS to clean the files (through its smudge/clean filter) to create a pointer file for Git to keep track of, and to store the large file.  This will always happen any time you refresh the index (such as with `git status`) and is unavoidable.

When that operation happens, Git LFS will create some temporary files in the course of its operations.  Usually these are cleaned up right away, but in some cases, they only get cleaned up after they become stale and Git LFS is invoked again.  This is normal and not a cause for concern.

Nothing here indicates an actual problem, and my suggestion is just to ignore it.  If you can't, and you need an actual copy of just the files in the working tree, consider `git -C SOURCE-DIRECTORY archive -o - HEAD | tar -C DESTINATION-DIRECTORY -xf -` after creating the destination directory.  This invokes `git archive` in the source repository to create a tar archive of the current commit to standard out, which is then extracted in the destination directory by `tar`, which reads the archive from standard input.  Note that this doesn't copy the Git data, only the files.

You could also clone the repository into the new location, but you won't have the exact same files, since you'll probably end up with one large pack file in the destination and no loose objects.

Comment: Thx for responding, bk2204.
Those files in ./.git/lfs/tmp are 0 bytes filesize each.
We like to use this new dir test/repo1 with the same git lfs server endpoint as original dir repo1 for some git migration work.

`git -C SOURCE-DIRECTORY archive -o - HEAD | tar -C DESTINATION-DIRECTORY -xf - `
Can you explain what these options do ? "archive -o - HEAD" and "-xf -" ?

Comment: You can use the repository you've created with `cp -R` with the original server without a problem; it's completely identical.  I've also updated the answer to explain the usage of that command.  Essentially, it's a `git archive` with the `-C` option to change directories to produce a tar archive, and a `tar` command with `-C` command to change directories to read the archive from standard input and extract it.  I refer you to the respective manual pages for details.